# Shopify API Search Parameters

Tags: ruby, shopify

I'm trying to get all of my customers that don't accept marketing but nothing seems to be working that I'm trying.

`ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(:all, :params => { accepts_marketing: false})`

I'm using the shopify_api Ruby gem.

Comment: what version rails do you use?

Comment: @wkaha I was trying with 1.9.3

Comment: i guess thats the ruby version. rails is something like 3.2.n … 4.0.n or below

Comment: Oh, oops, I'm using Rails 3.2.14, but that doesn't matter, this is a Ruby gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search endpoint is a little different than the usual. As you point out, your issue has nothing to do with Rails. Instead, just provide the endpoint with a little more information and you'll be fine. Try this:

```
ShopifyAPI::Customer.all( from: :search, params: {q: "accepts_marketing:true"})
```

You can search on customer email, whatever you need when you specify the endpoint as search on the Customer.